# Excel Macro that embeds images is having trouble looping

Tags: vba, excel, macros

An AMAZING user helped me to embed images vs. inserting images, so that when users use the macro to insert images and then send the workbook to others, the images would show.

[Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028899/excel-macro-places-images-but-they-do-not-appear-when-others-open-the-workbook)

I edited it to work for me and it for the most part, worked like a dream!

But now for the life of me, I cannot get this thing to loop properly. The images just pile one on top of each other. I read one other question on here that says it is related to resetting the path, but I am not sure how to do that, despite messing around a bit.

```
Dim repPic As Shape
Dim pictureNameColumn As Long
Dim picturePasteColumn As Long
Dim pictureColumn As Long
Dim pictureName As String
Dim lastPictureRow As Long
Dim pictureRow As Long
Dim pathForPicture As String
Dim Lft As Single
Dim Tp As Single
Dim Wdth As Single
Dim Hgth As Single
pictureNameColumn = 8
picturePasteColumn = 2
pictureRow = 4
pictureColumn = 8
lastPictureRow = Cells(Rows.Count, pictureNameColumn).End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
pathForPicture = "C:\Users\desid\images\"
Lft = Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn).Left + 30
Tp = Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn).Top + 3
Wdth = Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn).Width
Hgth = Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn).Height
Do While (pictureRow <= lastPictureRow)
pictureName = Cells(pictureRow, pictureColumn)

If (pictureName <> vbNullString) Then
If (Dir(pathForPicture & pictureName & ".jpg") <> vbNullString) Then
Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn).Select
Set repPic = Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(pathForPicture &             pictureName & ".jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, Lft, Tp, Wdth, Hgth)
repPic.Width = 90
repPic.Height = 90
Else
Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn) = "No Picture Found"
End If
Else
End If
pictureRow = pictureRow + 1
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: I think you need to adjust `Tp`. Iirc the values are relative to the worksheet, not the active cell.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am a total novice.. could you elaborate a bit about how I should change Tp? I am not understanding how I would adjust it to work for this scenario... I'm sorry. Thank you though!

Comment: You never change `Lft` and `Tp` so your pictures are all inserted at the same position. You need to update them according to your intentions (which I am not sure about). Since you probably want the pictures to be beneath each other you only need to update `Tp`

Comment: You were absolutely right!!!! Could you please answer the question so I could mark you as correct??? THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the line

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(..., msoFalse, msoTrue, Lft, Tp, Wdth, Hgth)
```

the coordinates `Lft` and `Tp` are relative to the sheet, not the active cell. So you need to update them for each picture, i.e. move the line `Tp = Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn).Top + 3` into the loop.